# I might have broken container port mapping

Tags: iptables, docker

Port mapping is not working. I don’t know if it was something I did or what.

**Setup**: `Arch Linux with kernel 5.16, Docker 20.10.12`, using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) with its acme companion to get certs for various apps in other containers. Everything was definitely working well.

Then all of a sudden I started getting `502` errors from the nginx proxy. It couldn’t reach the containerized apps on the ports I had specified. After investigating, I found out that the other containers were just opening up whatever ports they wanted to on the host. The host even thinks that the originally specified port is open, but it isn’t. So for example one of my apps is just nginx again serving a website. I have told Docker to map port `8001` on the host to `80` in the container. And then when I use `lsof` to show what ports are open on the host, I see 8001 in use. But then I can’t access anything on that, I can access it on port 80 (even though 80 is also in use by the nginx proxy). `nmap` confirms that it’s only port 80 that’s actually open on the container.

One thing I did recently was change the default policy in the FORWARD chain in iptables. I don’t see why changing the default would matter for packets that were already being routed somewhere.

**Config:**

Config of the nginx-proxy container:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123",
        "Created": "2022-03-02T16:16:07.626095681Z",
        "Path": "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "forego",
            "start",
            "-r"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2767,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-03-02T16:16:08.672491906Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:82ea330a72d6f9d955287dc6e2c4c57a1466d480688574a4d0997c981bc495f3",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123/e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123-json.log",
        "Name": "/nginx-proxy",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "btrfs",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "ivonet",
            "PortBindings": {
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Source": "nginx-proxy_conf",
                    "Target": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                    "VolumeOptions": {}
                },
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Source": "nginx-proxy_vhost",
                    "Target": "/etc/nginx/vhost.d",
                    "VolumeOptions": {}
                },
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Source": "nginx-proxy_html",
                    "Target": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                    "VolumeOptions": {}
                },
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Source": "nginx-proxy_certs",
                    "Target": "/etc/nginx/certs",
                    "ReadOnly": true,
                    "VolumeOptions": {}
                }
            ],
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "btrfs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "nginx-proxy_html",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-proxy_html/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "nginx-proxy_certs",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-proxy_certs/_data",
                "Destination": "/etc/nginx/certs",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": false,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                "Destination": "/tmp/docker.sock",
                "Mode": "ro",
                "RW": false,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "nginx-proxy_conf",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-proxy_conf/_data",
                "Destination": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "nginx-proxy_vhost",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-proxy_vhost/_data",
                "Destination": "/etc/nginx/vhost.d",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "nginx-proxy",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "443/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.21.6",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.7.2",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1",
                "NGINX_PROXY_VERSION=0.10.1-29-gfb8ddfd",
                "DOCKER_GEN_VERSION=0.8.2",
                "DOCKER_HOST=unix:///tmp/docker.sock"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "forego",
                "start",
                "-r"
            ],
            "Image": "nginxproxy/nginx-proxy:alpine",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/nginx/certs": {},
                "/etc/nginx/conf.d": {},
                "/etc/nginx/vhost.d": {},
                "/tmp/docker.sock": {},
                "/usr/share/nginx/html": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "3324b86760e2e436e707f1310aef7724e088d661c1bbeaaf573104e2644a08b0",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
                "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:82ea330a72d6f9d955287dc6e2c4c57a1466d480688574a4d0997c981bc495f3",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "nginx-proxy",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/home/winfield/contain/nginx-proxy/docker-compose.yaml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/winfield/contain/nginx-proxy",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "nginx-proxy",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "2.2.3",
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>",
                "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "Nicolas Duchon <nicolas.duchon@gmail.com> (@buchdag), Jason Wilder",
                "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2022-02-28T00:02:10.384Z",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Automated nginx proxy for Docker containers using docker-gen",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "MIT",
                "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "fb8ddfd08c0f6cb53e583ea22ff8be06f69c50dc",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "nginx-proxy",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "0.10.1-29-gfb8ddfd"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "cb385fa1d3dab87cccd2d89e70708e27e8bc1815867ae5fbc7e1c2f75000dc25",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cb385fa1d3da",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "ivonet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "nginx-proxy",
                        "nginx-proxy",
                        "e24130ccef2b"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "694e4c767b2eeca4c039e518db8294c2cc32a3be38f5dd0ad8779bce4099929c",
                    "EndpointID": "e653f85d0381f1c3bdaca9935eff3e4129d7941cf9c246d80e181e477c0bd79b",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Config of the proxied nginx container:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c",
        "Created": "2022-03-02T16:16:23.658997558Z",
        "Path": "/docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "nginx",
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 3633,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-03-02T16:16:24.099412527Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:bef258acf10dc257d641c47c3a600c92f87be4b4ce4a5e4752b3eade7533dcd9",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c/e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c-json.log",
        "Name": "/atsuo.tg",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "btrfs",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/winfield/contain/atsuo.tg/site:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "ivonet",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "btrfs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/winfield/contain/atsuo.tg/site",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "atsuotg",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "VIRTUAL_PORT=8001",
                "LETSENCRYPT_HOST=atsuo.tg",
                "VIRTUAL_HOST=atsuo.tg",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.21.6",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.7.2",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "Image": "nginx:alpine",
            "Volumes": {
                "/usr/share/nginx/html": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "1f56d3b21bfd2b60df186db7d9ee19865f777207a470f0f36fd37a27cd65acef",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "atsuotg",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/home/winfield/contain/atsuo.tg/docker-compose.yaml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/winfield/contain/atsuo.tg",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "atsuo.tg",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "2.2.3",
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "9339a100e64c7de59e3c6b9f00761ce9bc90789b8139daed8781c14bc91258e8",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/9339a100e64c",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "ivonet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "atsuo.tg",
                        "atsuo.tg",
                        "e0b1be5c35ff",
                        "atsuotg"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "694e4c767b2eeca4c039e518db8294c2cc32a3be38f5dd0ad8779bce4099929c",
                    "EndpointID": "6ccfdba4120787c39c71505403db08c67f32284637e5bbf2c4abbf0cdb8c15b7",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Config of the Docker custom bridge network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "ivonet",
        "Id": "694e4c767b2eeca4c039e518db8294c2cc32a3be38f5dd0ad8779bce4099929c",
        "Created": "2022-03-02T11:15:32.631561185-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "adac9051c7813cd9bab6747c798e058983c061b56fbcc9d5cee9d6dacd35461b": {
                "Name": "nginx-acme",
                "EndpointID": "15ae704194cf33bad77911800541de67f2ee099229014106af65b09d9bf58fa9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e0b1be5c35ff60f337087f58819be190dcf495796114b6a2054dd78cf0e4679c": {
                "Name": "atsuo.tg",
                "EndpointID": "6ccfdba4120787c39c71505403db08c67f32284637e5bbf2c4abbf0cdb8c15b7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e24130ccef2bce43a11ebe5686e9a0ca45a7b0b13e32c4649095d11fd0361123": {
                "Name": "nginx-proxy",
                "EndpointID": "e653f85d0381f1c3bdaca9935eff3e4129d7941cf9c246d80e181e477c0bd79b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Output of `iptables-save` on host:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Mar  2 15:59:49 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-694e4c767b2e -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-694e4c767b2e -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-694e4c767b2e ! -o br-694e4c767b2e -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-694e4c767b2e -o br-694e4c767b2e -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.3/32 ! -i br-694e4c767b2e -o br-694e4c767b2e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.3/32 ! -i br-694e4c767b2e -o br-694e4c767b2e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.4/32 ! -i br-694e4c767b2e -o br-694e4c767b2e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-694e4c767b2e ! -o br-694e4c767b2e -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-694e4c767b2e -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar  2 15:59:49 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Mar  2 15:59:49 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/24 ! -o br-694e4c767b2e -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.3/32 -d 172.18.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.3/32 -d 172.18.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.4/32 -d 172.18.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i br-694e4c767b2e -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i br-694e4c767b2e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:443
-A DOCKER ! -i br-694e4c767b2e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:80
-A DOCKER ! -i br-694e4c767b2e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.4:80
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar  2 15:59:49 2022
```

Output of `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` on host:

```
systemd-r  911 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  22667      0t0  TCP *:5355 (LISTEN)
systemd-r  911 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv6  22670      0t0  TCP *:5355 (LISTEN)
systemd-r  911 systemd-resolve   18u  IPv4  22673      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
systemd-r  911 systemd-resolve   20u  IPv4  22675      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.54:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       914            root    3u  IPv4  46226      0t0  TCP *:26506 (LISTEN)
sshd       914            root    4u  IPv6  46228      0t0  TCP *:26506 (LISTEN)
mariadbd   964           mysql   19u  IPv4  57354      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
mariadbd   964           mysql   21u  IPv6  57355      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2674            root    4u  IPv4  53545      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2681            root    4u  IPv6  62592      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2694            root    4u  IPv4  51280      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2700            root    4u  IPv6  53552      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 3591            root    4u  IPv4  50347      0t0  TCP *:8001 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 3597            root    4u  IPv6  46444      0t0  TCP *:8001 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Post your configuration for docker and nginx. Otherwise we're running blind.

Comment: @vidarlo ok I've added what I figure could help. The config for the inner nginx server is default, from the nginx:alpine image

Comment: This question will be missing details needed to answer it if and when the links go bad. Please ensure all the needed content to answer the question is included here and links are only for supplemental details.

Comment: @BMitch ok, that makes sense. I've moved everything to the body of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VIRTUAL_PORT` setting looks incorrect. You are using `VIRTUAL_PORT=8001` while the container is listening on port 80. So instead you should have `VIRTUAL_PORT=80`.

Connectivity between containers happens on a common user created network (e.g. `ivonet`), and on container ports. The published port on the host is for external users to access the container by connecting to the host port which gets forwarded to the container port.

Comment: Oh geez, that does it. I have a lot to learn :|